# React Native: Invoke a View on Button click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unity-game-engine

I'm a React Native noob.

I just integrated my Unity3D app with the React Native app using `nreact-native-unity-view` (https://github.com/nhancv/nreact-native-unity-view)

```
const onClick = () => {
   
  }


  return (
      <View  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text> React Native App</Text>
        <Button style={{ width: '100%' }} title="Open Unity Player" onPress={onClick}/>

      </View>
  );
};
```

This is the view which I want to call in `onClick` function

```
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <UnityView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                onMessage={onUnityMessage}
                onUnityMessage={onUnityMessage}
            />
          </View>
```

I tried searching for Navigation between screens in React Native. I couldn't really understand any. I need to go more in-depth to understand.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to use navigation and make it a separate page or show it in the same page ?

Comment: separate page would be better

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the stack navigator and have a separate page for the unity screen.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

the code to navigate would be navigation.navigate('screenname');
This code wont work until you sort the imports related to unity and related items.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const onClick = () => {
    navigation.navigate('UnityScreen');
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text> React Native App</Text>
      <Button
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        title="Open Unity Player"
        onPress={onClick}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function UnityScreen({ navigation }) {

  // your other code
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <UnityView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onMessage={onUnityMessage}
        onUnityMessage={onUnityMessage}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UnityScreen" component={UnityScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```